# How to hide actual link but not alert the affiliate that the link came from a redirected link?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

So far I've tried a simple page that 301 php redirects using the id (domain.com/link/1234/). Then I tried the same php redirect (forwards the id) to a php page uses id to et the uri to redirect using JavaScript (redirects using onload).

If I just click the link everything works fine. But redirecting receives a 404 from the affiliate company. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

I would like to have all of my links use the id of the post.

example: domain.com/link/1234/

instead of the affiliate link: affiliate.com/sniper.php?s=g&7=8&g=0

#### EDIT

So if I use this JavaScript in the head it redirects perfect.

```
<script>
    var url = "http://affiliate.com/sniper.php?s=g&7=8&g=0";

    // IE8 and lower fix
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/))
    {
        var referLink = document.createElement("a");
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    }

    // All other browsers
    else { window.location.replace(url); }
</script>
```

But if I add PHP into the JavaScript to add the URL dynamically. For example:

```
<script>

    var url = "<?php echo $url_to_affiliate_website; ?>";

    // IE8 and lower fix
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/))
    {
        var referLink = document.createElement("a");
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    }

    // All other browsers
    else { window.location.replace(url); }
</script>
```

This fails, I have zero idea why. PHP can be on this page but not after the script tag.

Any ideas??

Comment: `navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/)` will also return true in IE 10 and higher.

Comment: Could you please paste your final HTML code generated by PHP? I doubt that you're using that on a pure HTML file and that file is not parsed by PHP. I think we can locate the issue from your final HTML code by viewing source code form browser.

Comment: Your statement is not clear.. The URL is the only PHP as stated in the description. I've copied and pasted from mariaDB to make sure the URL is the same and even used an if statement to make sure URL is printing the same from the DB.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(url);` after setting the url variable and check your console to see if the url is passing in as expected

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a redirect rule that rewrite /link/{number}/ to link.php?id={number}

```
<?php
//link.php

//Consider sanitize the input. (if it's number, use (int) casting for instance)
$linkid = $_GET['id'];

/*
 Get the affiliate url based on the link ID.
 If you're using DB or whatever.
*/
$url = get_affiliate_url($linkid);

header("Location: ".$url);
?>
```

- Didn't test it.

Comment: Thank you for the try. As I said above, this is one of the first methods I tried. I'm not sure how the other end knows it is coming from a redirect - but they do. Other thoughts?

Comment: Another option I have in mind is using `Domain Masking`, i'm not a fan of this method and I don't know if it suits your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code you have used? I'm wondering how you are going to use a php variable inside a js functions.

Instead you should echo the php variable as php.

EX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var url = "<?php echo $url_to_affiliate_website; ?>";

        // IE8 and lower fix
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/))
        {
            var referLink = document.createElement("a");
            referLink.href = url;
            document.body.appendChild(referLink);
            referLink.click();
        }

        // All other browsers
        else { window.location.replace(url); }
    </script>
```

I think this will help you unless i have misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: My mistake. After trying several methods, my last attempt was to echo all of the JS along with the PHP Variable (sry for the confusion there). So, indeed I have tried to echo as you've written above and still the affiliate company/s (more than one) know their link is not being clicked, (I assume), so I receive a 404 instead of the intended offer.

For clarity, I'm editing the above code to reflect an echo. Thank you.

Comment: its ok...then what do u mean by "So if I use this JavaScript in the head it redirects perfect."?? are u telling if you hardcode the link it works..and if you dynamically generate, it doesnt work?

Comment: To add to that: I've tried every way I know to do it with PHP alone. JS with no PHP has been the only success I have had.

Comment: I dont see a reason why the dynamic one doesn't redirect properly because at the end of the day the hardcoded text and the dynamic url is treated the same inside the js function.

Comment: have you checked whether the hardcoded text and your dynamic text are same? I mean there might be any missing parameter while you dynamically generate the link...im not sure though...

Comment: I have. This works perfect on 90% of the URLs I have. There are just a hand full of companys who, I guess, do not like their links being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way you have tried to embed the PHP variable in the JavaScript. You have to do either this:

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "' . $url_to_affiliate_website . '";
    ...
    </script>';
?>
```

Or this:

```
// jump to the verbatim mode, aka not interpreted by the PHP parser
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "<?php echo $url_to_affiliate_website; ?>";
</script>
<?php // continue rest of the PHP code
```

Comment: Please see my comment on user3571366 answer. I've tried both ways. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Oops that answer is almost identical to mine. How did not I see that. :/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I just re-read your post; I'm not sure if that JavaScript is actually embedded in your document or in an external file, but if it's embedded, the file that's doing the redirect will need to be called "index.php" not "index.html" in order for the PHP to be evaluated. Likewise, if the JavaScript is in an external file, the JavaScript file instead of the HTML file will need a ".php" extension and be included in the page like so:

```
<script src="./javascript-file.php"></script>
```

As for the destination page knowing that the page was redirected, they are likely examining the HTTP headers and seeing that the page was 301 permanently redirected from your page. You may be able to prevent/remove those headers before redirecting to the affiliate. I'd need to see more of you're code to be able to assist with that.

Since you say that the PHP can't be after the script tag, I'm assuming that's a limitation of the hosting environment. Here's a solution that may work for you:

```
<div id="concealed" style="display:none;"><?php echo $url_to_affiliate_website; ?></div>

<script>
    var url = document.getElementById("concealed").innerHTML;

    // IE8 and lower fix
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/))
    {
        var referLink = document.createElement("a");
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    }

    // All other browsers
    else { window.location.replace(url); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url_to_affiliate_website = "http://affiliate.com/sniper.php?s=g&7=8&g=0"; 
?>
```

Are you sure the value your giving to **$url_to_affiliate_website** is the url you want ? 
Try also to rewrite your code this way. and use window.location instead

```
// IE8 and lower fix
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/))
{
    var referLink = document.createElement("a");
    referLink.href = "<?=$url_to_affiliate_website;?>"; // note the = after ?
    document.body.appendChild(referLink);
    referLink.click();
}

// All other browsers
else { 
window.location = url;
}
```

Also make sure you declaring the $url_to_affiliate_website before echoing it. And confirm if your file has a .php extension not .html

Save your file as UTF-8, if you use Notepad++, click Encoding->Encode in UTF8 then save your file and exit.